# simplesamlphp define the requested attributes

Tags: simplesamlphp

My simpleSAMLphp installation works, but I don't find out where to define the requested attributes below.

```
<saml:Issuer NameQualifier=” http://spid-sp.it” Format=" urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity " > SPID-sp-test</saml:Issuer><samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" /> <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:SpidL1</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

Can you tell me how I can configure this or which files i have to modify?

Thank you very much!